# Visual Studio 2017 Removes UWP App on Each Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I have a [UWP app](https://github.com/akshay2000/MonocleGiraffe) project that was created using Visual Studio 2105. I have started using the same solution in Visual Studio 2017. However, I have noticed that the app is removed and reinstalled on each deploy. So, all my pinned tiles, registered background tasks, app states are reset on each deploy making it difficult to debug.

I ensured that "Uninstall and then re-install my package." is unchecked in the project properties. I cannot find any other configuration controlling this behaviour. How do I solve this?

**Edit:** [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4pj0gaxp69dqon/VS2107BuildLog.txt) is the build output from Visual Studio while deploying the app in Debug configuration.

Comment: This is a very weird behavior. I know I have noticed app tiles to get unpinned, but not the application data to be cleared. I would try on another device, reinstall VS, and then potentially report as a bug.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Cleaning up the system is one way. But I'd rather not do it. Things work fine in VS2015. Tiles don't get unpinned. I'm choosing clean install as a last resort.

Comment: Then reinstall of VS2017 seems as a non-invasive thing to try. That or you could also try to install the Preview version of VS to see if the problem happens there as well

Comment: Can you provide diagnostics build logs? In Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run and set "MSBuild project build output verbosity:" to "Diagnostic". Next, reproduce the issue and copy the output to a log file and share if possible (some shared cloud storage, perhaps?)

Comment: @DanielJacobson Added the build output.

Answer (score 0):

On the StartUp project - right click and select properties. Select Debug tab.

Untick "Uninstall and then re-install my package. All information about the application state is deleted."

Comment: From the question:

> I ensured that "Uninstall and then re-install my package."

That doesn't help.

Comment: @akshay2000 In any case, some other person might try to look for similar problem and find a solution in my answer. Sorry it didn't help in your case.